# How to edit the master-config.yaml when using oc cluster up

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-client-tools, openshift-3

I'm using `oc cluster up` to create a local test environment for my project and I need to add a CORS rule to the `master-config.yml`.

When I start my cluster using `oc cluster up` a directory called `openshift.local.clusterup` is created in the same directory, inside this directory there are multiple sub-directories that contains multiple `master-config.yml` (`kube-apiserver/`, `openshift-apiserver/` and `openshift-controller-manager/`)

I've tried to edit all config files and to restart the openshift (`docker restart origin`) and also to stop and start the full cluster (`oc cluster down` -> `oc cluster up --use-existing-config` ) but the configuration is not applied.

Any idea? Is it possible to do it? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you restart the cluster are the changes still there?

Comment: I've made a couple more tests, and now when I restart the cluster it seems to work, I'm also making first `oc cluster up --write-config` then I edit the `master-config.yml` and I do `oc cluster up` to start the cluster